# How to query all records when all method is undefined?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, youtube-api

I'm trying to search the comments of a given YouTube video in order to see if it contains a specific string.

*My api call using the [Yt gem](https://fullscreen.github.io/yt/comments.html) is working just fine. However, I'm struggling because `.all` and certain SQL queries are not working as the response collection seems to be lazy loaded.*

**Question** -- How can I query the CommentThreads collection to see which of its items contain a specific string like "parts?

Below is the console output of a few expressions that I have tried to run, including a LIKE query:

```
@video_comments
=> #<Yt::Collections::CommentThreads:0x007fe626f70120>


@video_comments.all
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `all' for #<Yt::Collections::CommentThreads:0x007fe626f70120>


@video_comments.first.text_display
=> "Links for the parts in the description! <br /><br />What color do you want?"


@video_comments.first.text_display.include? "parts"
=> true


@video_comments.where('text_display LIKE ?', "%parts%").first
=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)
from /Users/macbook/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/yt-0.28.5/lib/yt/collections/base.rb:37:in `where'
```

Rails 5.0.1 + ruby 2.3.0p0 + psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.1

EDIT: actual `@video_comments` response https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7fQf.jpg

Comment: have you tried `to_a` instead of `all`?

Answer (score 0):

`.all` works for Model e.g. if you have a model VideoComments, then `VideoComments.all` will return all comments.
Your last query should work, you just have a syntax error, try

```
    @video_comments.where('text_display iLIKE = ?', "%parts%").first
```

Comment: `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)`

Answer (score 0):

First, @video_comments itself not an active record. So, you can not use `@video_comments.all`

According to the commentThreads by google, the response return should be like:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "snippet": {
    "channelId": string,
    "videoId": string,
    "topLevelComment": comments Resource,
    "canReply": boolean,
    "totalReplyCount": unsigned integer,
    "isPublic": boolean
  },
  "replies": {
    "comments": [
      comments Resource
    ]
  }
}
```

So, you instead of using `@video_comments.all` your command should be:

```
@video_comments.replies.comments
```

(Try with `@video_comments["replies"]["comments"]` if not success)

It should return you a list of comments.

Ok, next step you will filter the list of comments to get comment that content 'part' word.

```
@video_comments.replies.comments.select{|comment| comment.text_display.include? "parts"}
```

Something like that.

Please refer to the following link for the details:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads

Comment: @Thanh_Tuong Here is a look at the actual response: http://imgur.com/bjkXWfO So I tried to access `replies` in all of the ways you mentioned. I also tried `.items` `[items]` `["items"]` or `snippet` etc. But they all say undefined method.

Comment: Hi @HashRocketSyntax, please try this way .instance_variable_get("@#{items}")

Comment: @Thanh_Tuong Thank you for your help. `NameError: undefined local variable or method "items" for #<ScansController:0x007fe633b83c58>`

Comment: Could you please remove the {} and try with this one : .instance_variable_get("@items") @HashRocketSyntax

Comment: Interesting `@video_comments.instance_variable_get("@items")` results in `nil`. I'm having some success with `each`, but this way might be more elegant if it works

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar and finally got it working by referring to:

`video_comments['items'][0]['snippet']['data']['textOriginal']`

(This would return the actual comment. Then that text could be searched.)
 
It would not work without the single quotes, or without the [0] (without quotes) after `['items']`.

`Items` is an array with a single element that includes a nest of arrays and hashes. If I tried searching the entire `Items` array, it only returned the names of the nested hashes and arrays inside it; not their content.

The only way I found to get the actual content was to refer directly to the element I wanted (in this case, the comment text in `['textOriginal']`.